# Android Activity Stack Manipulation

Tags: android, android-activity

I have activity A and B. A is the activity that loads when the app is launched and when they click a button a new intent is made to go to activity B. When I click a button in B I want to put activity A on the top of the stack so when I click the activity A button again it loads my onResume() for activity B instead of my onCreate().

How would I do this?

Comment: Have you tried calling `finish()` in Activity B? That should do exactly that.

Comment: Your question is not clear. You want to have a button in B that, when clicked, moves the existing instance of A from the bottom to the top of the stack? Then you say "when I click the activity A button again it loads my `onResume()` for B instead of `onCreate()`. This is unclear. What is "activity A button"? Where is this? It seems that you want to reuse the existing instance of B but I cannot follow all this. Please elaborate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use intent flags to achieve this

```
FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP is the best option here.
```

As per the developer site

> If the activity being started is already running in the current task,
>   then instead of launching a new instance of that activity, all of the
>   other activities on top of it are destroyed and this intent is
>   delivered to the resumed instance of the activity (now on top),
>   through onNewIntent()).

Example of how you set FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP

```
  findViewById(R.id.button2).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent i = new Intent(Main3Activity.this, Main2Activity.class);
            i.putExtra("HELLO","HI");
            i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP|
                    Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });
```

In receiving activity

```
  @Override
    protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
        super.onNewIntent(intent);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), intent.getExtras().get("HELLO").toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }
```

Comment: I am doing that but now when i try to intent.putExtra("val", input); the activty shows that this is null, how can i pass a string with using this?

Comment: final String myInput = getIntent().getStringExtra("val");

Comment: That returns null, there is no error in the console log

Comment: did you implement onnewIntent ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203618/discussion-between-jacks-and-user3277468).